# Why is the preimage of zero of a global section of a locally constant sheaf closed?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I'm reading *Faisceaux Algébriques Cohérents* (Serre), no.36 lemma 2. The proof of that lemma states that the preimage of zero of a global section of a sheaf is closed when the sheaf is locally constant.

I know the preimage of zero is open (because it is a sheaf), but I can't understand why locally constant implies it closed.

Comment: If $f(x)\neq 0$, and if $U$ is a connected neighborhood of $x$ such that your local system is constant, then for any $y\in U$, $f(y)=f(x)\neq 0$. Hence, the complementary of the zero set is open.

Comment: a locally constant sheaf on a top. space means for any point in the top. space, there exists an open n.b.d s.t. all stalks of  points in the n.b.d are the same abelian group.

Comment: This definition is not correct, because in your definition, the sheaf of holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ would be locally constant. It require the stronger assumption that for any $x$ there is a (connected) neighborhood $U$ such that $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{F})\rightarrow\mathcal{F}_y$ is an isomorphism for any $y\in U$.

Comment: what if there doesn't exist any connected neighborhood ?

Comment: Algebraic and analytic sets are locally connected, so that is not an issue in FAC. However, the more general definition of locally constant is the following : $\mathcal{F}$ is locally constant if it is locally isomorphic to a constant sheaf, that is a sheaf of continuous function $U\rightarrow E$ where $E$ is a discrete set.

Comment: that's what I want to say, and I want to know the argument in general top. space. thank you !

Comment: The proof is (almost) the same. If $f(x)\neq 0$, fix $U$ a neighborhood of $x$ such that your local system is constant, that is the sheaf of function $U\rightarrow E$ to a discrete set. Then $f$ is non zero on the open subset of $U$ $f^{-1}(E\setminus \{0\})$.

Comment: however, the total space F is not U x E(U), F has been given a topology, what's the topology of U x E(U) ?

Comment: I don't see how it affects what I said. Let us change notations because no one writes $F(U)$ for the restriction of $F$ on $U$. So let's assume that $F$ is constant with value $E$. Then $\Gamma(U,F)$ is the set of continuous functions $f:U\rightarrow E$ where $E$ is given the discrete topology, and then $f^{-1}(E\setminus\{0\})$ is open. Now if you want the topology on the total space of $F$, this is $U\times E$ with the product topology.

Comment: Note that Serre's definition of sheaf in FAC is a bit old-fashioned. I don't know if people uses this definition anymore. But of course, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I write E(U) because E is depend on U ( locally constant ) and f is a continuous section from the base X to the total space F (with its topology). now, choose a nbd U of x s.t. the sheaf restrict on U is a constant sheaf with value E(U). What does " f : U -> E " mean ?

Comment: Well, it means a function from $U$ to $E$... I mean, $E$ is just a set and $F$ is the constant sheaf with value $E$, so that the total space of $F$ is $U\times E$ and a section of $F$ is a continuous function $f:U\rightarrow E$. (If $F$ is a sheaf, $F(U)$ generally means the set of section of $F$ defined over $U$, which is not Serre's notation).

Comment: I mean that originally, f : X -> F, how to get f : U -> E, and what's the topology of E induced by F ?

Comment: As I said, you can easily reduce to the case where $F$ is constant, because you want to find an open subset where your section is non zero, and it is enough to find an open subset inside an open subset where $F$ is constant. So let's assume that $F$ is constant on $U$ with value $E$. It means that (the total space of) $F$ is homeomorphic to $U\times E$ with the product topology and $E$ discrete. Hence a section on $U$ is just a continuous function $f:U\rightarrow E$.

Comment: what's the explicit transform on f ?  restriction, composition...?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: the explicit operation ( formally ) on f : X -> F to get f' : U -> E

Comment: Ok I see, take $f:X\rightarrow F$, restrict to $U$ and compose with the homeo $F_{|U}\simeq U\times E$ and finally project onto $E$. Conversely, take $f':U\rightarrow E$, then take $f':U\rightarrow U\times E$ to be $(id,f')$ and compose with the homeo to get a section of $F$ over $U$.

Answer (score 0):

This is an abstract of the above comments.

Serre uses the "espace étalé" version of sheaves, so let me recall the definition of constant and locally constant sheaves.

A sheaf $F$ on $X$ is said to be constant if there exist a discrete set $E$ such that $F$ is homeomorphic to $X\times E$ with the product topology, and such that the projection $\pi:F\rightarrow X$ corresponds to the first projection. In that case, there is a bijection between sections of $F$ defined on an open subset $U$ and continuous function $U\rightarrow E$.

The bijection is the following : given a section $s:U\rightarrow F$, compose with the homeomorphism $F\simeq X\times E$ and compose with the second projection. This gives a continuous map $f:U\rightarrow E$. Conversely, given a continuous map $f:U\rightarrow E$, takes its graph, that is, consider the map $U\rightarrow X\times E$ where the first coordinate is simply the inclusion, and the second coordinate is $f$. Finally, compose with the homeomorphism $X\times E\simeq F$ to get a section $U\rightarrow F$.

You should check that this correspondence is indeed a bijection.

A sheaf $F$ is said to be locally constant if there exists a open covering $X=\bigcup U_i$ such that the restriction $F_i$ of $F$ to $U_i$ is constant.

Now let us prove that if $s$ is a section of a locally constant sheaf of abelian groups, then the set where $s(x)=0$ is closed.

Let $x\in X$ be a point where $s(x)\neq 0$. There exist an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $F$ is constant on $U$ with value $E$. Hence the section corresponds to a continuous map $f:U\rightarrow E$. But then, we have $\{x\in U, s(x)\neq 0\}=f^{-1}(E\setminus\{0\})$ which is open. So the complementary of the zero set of $s$ is open.